# Defining and calling a function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create functions using def that can be called later in the code:

- is_leap_year(year) Given a year (a 4 digit number), returns true if it is a leap year, and false otherwise.  
- month_name(number) Given the number of a month, returns the corresponding name. 1 is January, ..., 12 is December.   
- days_in_month(month_number, year) Given a month (in the form of a number) and (4 digit) year, return the number of days in the month (accounting, in the case of February, for whether or not it is a leap year).
- first_day_of_year(year) Given a 4 digit year, return the number of the day on which January 1st falls. 0 is Sunday, …, 6 is Saturday. (See question 2 of assignment 2.) 
- first_day_of_month(month_number, year) Given a month (in the form of a number) and (4 digit) year, return the number of the day on which the first of that month falls. 0 is Sunday, …, 6 is Saturday.

how would I do this?

code:

```
def print_welcome():
    print('Test harness for calutils');

def get_selection():
    print('\nChoose from the following options:')
    print('0. quit')
    print('1. Test is_leap_year().')
    print('2. Test month_name().')
    print('3. Test days_in_month().')
    print('4. Test first_day_of_year().')
    print('5. Test first_day_of_month().')
    return int(input())


def test_leap_year():
    from calutils import is_leap_year

    year = int(input('Enter the year (4 digits):\n'))
    if is_leap_year(year):
        print('The year '+str(year)+' is a leap year.')
    else:
        print('The year '+str(year)+' is not leap year.')

def test_month_name():
    from calutils import month_name

    for month_number in range(1, 13):
        print('Month number '+str(month_number)+ ' is '+month_name(month_number)+'.')


def test_days_in_month():
    from calutils import days_in_month

    year = int(input('Enter the year (4 digits):\n'))
    for month_number in range(1, 13):
        print('The days in the month with number '+str(month_number)+ ' in year '+str(year)+' is '+str(days_in_month(month_number, year))+'.')

def test_first_day_year():
    from calutils import first_day_of_year

    year = int(input('Enter the year (4 digits):\n'))
    print('The first day of '+str(year)+' is '+str(first_day_of_year(year))+'.')

def test_first_day_month():
    from calutils import first_day_of_month

    month = int(input('Enter the month (1 for January, ..., 12 for December):\n'))
    year = int(input('Enter the year (4 digits):\n'))
    print('The first day of month '+str(month)+' in '+str(year)+' is '+str(first_day_of_month(month, year))+'.')

def main():
    print_welcome()

    selection = get_selection()
    while not selection==0:

        if selection==1:
            test_leap_year()
        elif selection==2:
            test_month_name()
        elif selection==3:

            test_days_in_month()
        elif selection==4:
            test_first_day_year()
        elif selection==5:
            test_first_day_month()
        else:
            print('That selection was not recognised.')

        selection = get_selection()


main()
```

Comment: Can you be more precise in your question ?
Is the code above not working as intended ? Is the behavior abnormal ?

Comment: no, I need to write a separate code consisting of functions and it will be called in the code above

Comment: how do I define the functions that I need